# How to add tslib plugin in qtwebbrowser application?

Tags: qt, qt5, embedded-linux, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

I'm trying to run a web based application on an embedded hardware using QT Web browser using qws eglfs frame buffer. I'm trying to include tslib for the touchscreen to work properly but couldn't figure out how to add the tslib plugin in qt web browser. Facing an issue saying that no plugin detected. Any idea on how to solve this?
P.S: There is no X11 server. It's just on frame buffer.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure its installed.
You then can define

```
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_TSLIB=1
```

or start the app with

```
/path/to/app - plugin tslib
```